# Implicit invocation of operator [C++]

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I defined two classes:

```
class Token_
{
public:
    virtual char operator*()const = 0;//this fnc cannot run implicitly
protected:
    Token_()
    {   }
    Token_(const Token_&);
    Token_& operator=(const Token_&);
};
```

and second:

```
class Operator : public Token_
    {
    public:
    Operator(const char ch):my_data_(token_cast<Operator_enm>(ch))
    {   }
    Operator_enm get()const
    {
        return my_data_;
    }
    Operator_enm set(const Operator_enm& value)
    {
        Operator_enm old_value = get();
        my_data_ = value;
        return old_value;
    }
    char operator*()const//this operator has to be invoke explicitly
    {
        return static_cast<char>(my_data_);
    }
private:
    Operator_enm my_data_;
};
```

and later on in program I have something like this:

```
template<class R>
R Calculator::expr_()const
{
    Token_* token = read_buffer_();
    switch (*token)//here if I use explicit call of operator*() it works
    {
    case PLUS:
        {
            R result ;//not defined yet
            return result;
        }
    case MINUS:
        {
            R result ;//not defined yet
            return result;
        }
    default:
        cerr << "Bad expr token.";
    }

}
```

Why this call of operator*() can't be implicit? Is there any way to make it implicit?
Thank you.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by implicit.  Do you mean that it doesn't compile unless you write:
switch(operator*(token))?

Comment: Yes, I have to write token->operator*() to successfully compile.

Comment: I highly suggest renaming the Operator class as it is only case difference from the reserved word `operator`.  Usually this is bad form since there could be an easy typo but very hard to find.

Comment: I cannot agree more with you Operator as name is very poor style. Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`token` is a pointer to a `Token_` object, not a `Token_` object itself, thus the `*` operator in the switch statement dereferences only the pointer (thereby only obtaining the object), but doesn't then continue to call the operator you defined.

Try instead:

```
switch(*(*token)) {
```

The use of your custom `operator *` might be a bit confusing now though.

Another options is to alter `read_buffer_()` such that you can do the following:

```
Token_ token = read_buffer_(); // NOTE: read_buffer_() returns a Token_ object directly
switch (*token)//here if I use explicit call of operator*() it works
```

In that case, `Token_` objects mimic pointers, and you wouldn't return pointer to pointers normally either.

Comment: ...So to invoke your defined operator, write `**token`.

Comment: Works, thanks. I wonder how many years one have to spend with pointers to not get surprised by them?

Answer (score 0):

The other option is instead of:

```
Token_* token = read_buffer_();
```

do:

```
Token_& token = *read_buffer_();
```